# How do I find out if a video is actual or if it was modified with a Software?

Tags: video, editing, effects, color-grading, special-effects

This video in question is [Chameleon Changing Color](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ioblgpA5eTo) How do I find out if that color change in the Chameleon is real and not a modification that was done with software? Specifically, I am looking for some software I can use to conduct the analysis or a website that provides such services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chameleons do have some pretty wild colors they can change into, and the process is extremely advanced, requiring physicists and biologists to fully understand how it works; [check out this video for how it works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQggDnScsvI). Personal note: Something this advanced doesn't happen by random chance.

Anyway, my personal opinions aside, it appears to me, this video was heavily edited by software to get a bigger wow factor. I've edited photos and videos for the better part of 20 years and there are subtle markers that stand out to me.

The biggest tip-off, is at 2:06 into the video when the Chameleon changes blue. If you look carefully at the body, you will see a slight gray outline around the edge of the entire Chameleon, it is especially noticeable at the top of his back and the around his forward paw gripping the branch -- that is a not so subtle sign that a poorly made mask has been used to select an area for manipulation. Other tipoffs include the vibrancy of the colors and the purple/blue, and the whole body changing the same color, instead of patches changing color.

As for what software can do this, there are many. If it's a still image you can use Affinity photo, Gimp, or Photoshop. For video, the best (and free) is [DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve/) is what I would recommend. It was specifically designed to do this kind of work!

For an example of how the change could have been done in software, [check out this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DmcV4TI0JVQ) or [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VeeWGSdSHPM).

**How it happens in Chamelons**

**How it's done is software**

Comment: Thankyou @NinteenEighty, I have accepted your answer. I am also looking for some forensic tools to detect the edited videos since I have no expertise :-)

Answer (score -1):

Before going too far, i don't think there is something on earth would like wasting energy to keep changing appearance for nothing, or do you think it knows it is on TV and know where the camera is? Come on!

Someone plz tells me i am wrong.

Comment: I am done in here, before that may i share two articles from The Verge

1) https://www.theverge.com/2018/6/22/17487764/adobe-photoshopped-fakes-edit-spotted-using-machine-learning-ai
2) https://www.theverge.com/2019/6/14/18678782/adobe-machine-learning-ai-tool-spot-fake-facial-edits-liquify-manipulations

Good luck!

Comment: Hi xer-xer, could you edit your answer to include a bit more context? At the moment it's not clear what you mean (without having access to your thoughts).

Comment: since the answer has been marked as -1, i have no interest to edit it at all. my answer means to understand more about your objects you will know more what you want to get. In this case, images of chameleon can found from Google as your data set; classification would help. I have provided articles, and i am done in here.

Comment: The -1 merely indicates that your answer, in its current form, is not clear or not helpful. By editing it you can clarify it and get a +1 (or +2, +3, +4, etc... if it's really clear and helpful). Of course if you're not interested in writing clear answers and just want to share your raw thoughts that's fine as well, but then probably this Q&A format is not an ideal match for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @xer-rex. It is a philosophical one. Thank you :-) I am looking for one that is more technical. It is not about this video alone although it can be taken as a sample. I want to use the method for other videos also that I come across in the future. Thank you for the articles in your first comment. They were new knowledge to me as I am new to this field :-)